# Hover event not working with biggest z-index

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, background-color, opacity

I have a gallery item with some image in its body. It has to display MORE link in the center of the body when I hover over gallery item (which works just fine) and display 0.5 opacity when I hover over MORE link. Even though z-index is bigger than parent's, for some reason :hover event simply does not fire. Any clue on how to fix this? My cursor: pointer also does not work.
HTML:

```
<div class="gallery _flex-between">
            <div class="gallery__item gallery-item _flex-column-center">
                <a href="/project/everlastingSummer" class="gallery-item__link"></a>
                <div class="gallery-item__body">
                    <div class="gallery-item__more-container">
                        <a class="gallery-item-more">More &#8594;</a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="/resources/projects/1.jpg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
                </div>
                <div class="gallery-item__footer">
                    Everlasting Summer
                </div>
            </div>
       </div>
```

CSS:

```
    ._absolute-cover {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .gallery {
        margin-top: 4em;
        width: 90%;
    }
    .gallery-item__footer {
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        margin-top: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 35px;
        padding: .5em 0;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
        background-color: white;
        transition: background-color .3s, color .3s;
    }
    .gallery__item {
        position: relative;
        width: 30%;
        max-width: 600px;
    }
    .gallery-item__more-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
        transition: background-color .3s;
        border-radius: 35px;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .gallery-item__link {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        cursor: default;
        z-index: 4;
    }
    .gallery-item-more {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1000000000;
        width: 50%;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
        opacity: 0;
        transition: background-color .3s;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        padding: 1em 0;
        border-radius: 35px;
        text-align: center;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .gallery-item-more:hover {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    }
    .gallery-item__link:hover ~ .gallery-item__footer {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }
    .gallery-item__link:hover ~ .gallery-item__body .gallery-item__more-container {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    }
    .gallery-item__link:hover ~ .gallery-item__body .gallery-item-more {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .gallery-item__body {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    ._flex-column-center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

    .gallery__img {
        object-position: top;
        height: 25vw;
        width: 100%;
        border-radius: 35px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the image before the more-button and it should work: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Kathara/pen/GRGEmrZ)

```
<div class="gallery _flex-between">
    <div class="gallery__item gallery-item _flex-column-center">
        <a href="/project/everlastingSummer" class="gallery-item__link"></a>
        <div class="gallery-item__body">
            <img src="/resources/projects/1.jpg" alt="" class="gallery__img">
            <div class="gallery-item__more-container">
                <a class="gallery-item-more">More &#8594;</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery-item__footer">
            Everlasting Summer
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Generally it's like this that siblings that come after this element have the higher z-index. I've struggled with z-index a lot and found that if the structure can easily be adapted then it's worth doing so. Otherwise it might take a while to fix or even be unfixable. :)